# Ошибка импорта tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Новичок в tensorflow. Решил добавить его в свой проект. Никак не могу убрать предупреждения в консоли:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.graph_view has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.graph_view. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.python_state has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.python_state. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.functional_saver has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.functional_saver. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.checkpoint_options has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_options. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
```

Также данный способ никак не помогает:

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1-4'
```

Comment: почему не последовать совету и не изменить пути импорта?

Comment: Что изменить, как изменить?

Comment: приблизительный перевод ошибки `Пжалуйста исправьте ваши импорты. Модуль tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate Перемещён в  tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate. Старый модуль будет удалёв в версии 2.11.`  то есть нужно писать не `import tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate` а `import tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate`